# Correct form of the convection term in the Navier-Stokes equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes

Usually the NS momentum equation for an compressible fluid is written in its convecting form, in the absence of external forces, as

$$
\rho\frac{\partial \vec u}{\partial t} +\rho(\vec u\cdot\nabla)\vec u+\nabla P = \mu\nabla^2\vec u
+\frac{\mu}{3}\nabla(\nabla\cdot \vec u)
$$

However, from the Wikipedia, this can be written in "conservation form", as

$$
\rho\frac{\partial \vec u}{\partial t} +\rho\nabla\cdot (\vec u\otimes\vec u)+\nabla P = \mu\nabla^2\vec u
+\frac{\mu}{3}\nabla(\nabla\cdot \vec u)
$$

I can't see how these two are consistent, the convection term in the lower one is

$$
\nabla_\alpha(u_\alpha u_\beta) = \vec u\nabla\cdot \vec u + (\vec u\cdot \nabla)\vec u
$$

So there's an extra term $\vec u\nabla\cdot \vec u$ with respect to the first equation.

What am I not understanding here? I see that for incompressible fluids, there's a pressure equations that constraints the system to obey $\nabla\cdot \vec u=0$, but I'm still missing something about the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have changed the equation from what is in Wikipedia.
You have
$$
\rho\frac{\partial{\bf v }}{\partial t}+\rho \nabla\cdot ({\bf v}\otimes {\bf v})+\ldots
$$
Wiki's conservation form  has an  expression with the  $\rho$'s in the correct places
$$
\frac{\partial{\rho \bf v }}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot (\rho({\bf v}\otimes {\bf v}))+\ldots
$$
The extra bit they add to the plain Euler equation is
$$
{\bf v}\left( \frac{\partial \rho }{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot (\rho {\bf v})\right) 
$$
which is zero by the continuity equation.

Comment: I guess, for further clarification, that I assumed that the pressure is constant along the fluid which is pretty much the definition of incompressible. Thanks!

Comment: Mmmm... No. In an incompressible fluid the pressure can be very big. It's the density that does not change!  I guess that's what you means though,

Comment: Yes I was thinking density and wrote pressure... sorry, and thanks again.